# PHP change array structure

Tags: php, arrays

I have an existing array in this following structure,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)


And, I want to convert in the following structure:

Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 3
        )

)
```

Any suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use a map to iterate over the array items and return a new array for each one of them.

```
<?php
function map($n) {
    return [
        'class_id' => $n
    ];
}

$a = array(1, 3);
$b = array_map("map", $a);
print_r($b);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

U just need to foreach this like this:

```
$data = [1, 3];
$result = [];

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $result[] = ["class_id" => $item];
}
```

Seems that is exactly u need )

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

`array_walk($data, function(&$n){ $n = ['class_id'=>$n]; })`

Keep in mind that we:

1. Pass the array as a reference to `array_walk`.
2. Then we pass each element as a reference to modify its content.

Also, `array_walk` keeps your index intact.